# Spark SparkFiles.get() returns driver path instead of worker path

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, rdd, executor

I am piping the partitions of an RDD through an external executable. I use sparkContext.addFiles() so that the executable will be available to the workers.

I when I attempt to run the code I am getting FileNotFound Exceptions for the executable file and it would appear that running SparkFiles.getfile() returns the  driver location when I would expect it to return the worker location.

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile("/dbfs/FileStore/Custom_Executable")
files_rdd  = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(files_list)

print(f'spark file path:{SparkFiles.get("Custom_Executable")}')

path_with_params =  SparkFiles.get("Custom_Executable") + " the-function-name  --to 
company1 --from  company2 -input - -output -"

print(f'path with params: {path_with_params}')

pipe_rdd = files_rdd.pipe(path_with_params,  env={'SOME_ENV_VAR': env_var_val})

print(pipe_tokenised_rdd.collect())
```

this outputs..

```
spark file path:/local_disk0/spark-c69e5328-9da3-4c76-85b8-a977e470909d/userFiles- 
e8a37109-046c-4909-8dd2-95bde5c9f3e3/Custom_Executable
exe path: /local_disk0/spark-c69e5328-9da3-4c76-85b8-a977e470909d/userFiles-e8a37109- 
046c-4909-8dd2-95bde5c9f3e3/Custom_Executable the-function-name  --to company1 --from  
company2 -input - -output -
Output
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 
0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 12) 
(10.113.4.168 executor 0): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: 
&#39;FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: &#39;/local_disk0/spark- 
c69e5328-9da3-4c76-85b8-a977e470909d/userFiles-e8a37109-046c-4909-8dd2- 
95bde5c9f3e3/Custom_Executable&#39;&#39;. Full traceback below:
```

Why is the pipe Sparkfiles.get() returning the driver path and not the worker path?

Comment: Why not run the command directly from DBFS? Or copy it to nodes using the init script?

Comment: I am Alex. But I am also trying to understand why the file  added through sparkContext.addFiles() is not being found when the pipe command executes using the path from sparkFiles.get().

Answer (score 0):

After many tests, I noticed that the Spark document says:

> `SparkFiles.get(file_name)` returns the worker path.

But it does not, instead it returns driver path. However, the `sparkContext.addFile()` method adds a file to all the nodes in the cluster.

I don't know why it is like this. Maybe this is a bug in Spark (I'm using 3.5.0 version).